# Now Playing app stopped working on Apple Watch after upgrading iPhone to iOS 17.4

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos

**Since I updated my Apple iPhone 14 Pro Max to [iOS 17.4](https://support.apple.com/en-us/118723), I can no longer control the audio playback from my [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/112022) with the [Now Playing](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/now-playing-apd4ea5db227/6.0/watchos/6.0) app.**

| [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/112022) | Apple iPhone 14 Pro Max |
| --- | --- |
| Model A1758 | Model A2894 |
| [watchOS 6.3](https://support.apple.com/en-us/118388) | <s>iOS 17.4</s> [iOS 17.4.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/118723) |
| 14 Dec 2020 | 07 Mar 2024 |

The **[Now Playing](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/now-playing-apd4ea5db227/6.0/watchos/6.0)** app *should let* you control audio playback on Apple Watch, iPhone, and other devices.

Since March 7th, 2024, the [Now Playing](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/now-playing-apd4ea5db227/6.0/watchos/6.0) app on my [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/112022) displays an endless spinning wheel demonstrating that it cannot connect to my iPhone 14.

#### Failed Troubleshooting Attempts

1. Switching off the [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/112022) and the Apple iPhone 14 Pro Max did not solve the problem.
2. [Forcing](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-220564/) the [Now Playing](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/now-playing-apd4ea5db227/6.0/watchos/6.0) app to quit did not solve the problem.
3. Toggling the **Auto-Launch Audio Apps** option OFF and then back ON, in the Watch app on the iPhone, under Settings > General > Wake Screen did not solve the problem.
4. [Deleting](https://www.myhealthyapple.com/now-playing-app-not-working-on-apple-watch-lets-fix-it/) and re-installing the Now Playing app did not solve the problem.
5. [Unpairing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/108372) the [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/112022) and restoring it to its factory settings did not solve the problem.

#### Some Online Bug Reports

1. [Now playing on Apple Watch not working after update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254765567?sortBy=newest_first#260320368022)
2. [Apple Watch’s Now Playing Issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252833238?sortBy=newest_first)
3. [Now Playing State Not Updating on Apple Watch](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728212)
4. [Apple watch crown does not regulate volume in Now Playing after update](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747224)
5. [Now playing Apple Watch 3 series not working after watchos 5 update. What to do?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8554444?sortBy=newest_first)
6. [Now playing on Apple Watch not working after update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254765567?&sortBy=newest_first)
7. ["Now Playing" App Not Working on Apple Watch](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252650881?sortBy=newest_first)
8. [“Now playing” not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/1bctibt/now_playing_not_working/)
9. [My Apple Watch running watchOS 6.3 no longer displays my iPhone in the 'Now Playing'](https://twitter.com/andersofsydney/status/1772182546635243523)
10. [Now Playing app stopped working on Apple Watch ⌚ after upgrading iPhone to iOS 17.4 ⁉️](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/471485/96921)
11. [iOS 17.4: Now Playing not working on Apple Watch](https://gist.github.com/JV-conseil/55b94bcb5f5e79084d786476a956718f)

#### *Update March 21st, 2024*

The release of [iOS 17.4.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/118723) on March 21st, 2024 did not solve the problem

[image: Now Playing on Apple Watch not working since Apple iOS 17.4]